# Add prefix to ItemSource values in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, itemsource

This is in my app.xaml file (cut down):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="SongTitleString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 1"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 2"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 3"/>
    </x:Array>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is the class:

```
namespace OCLMEditor
{
    /// This class provides us with an object to fill a ComboBox with
    /// that can be bound to string fields in the binding object.
    public class ComboBoxItemString
    {
        public string ValueString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the markup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboSongOpen" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SongTitleString}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="ValueString" 
    SelectedValuePath="ValueString" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding SongTitle}">
    <ComboBox.MaxWidth>
        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
            ElementName="textWeeklyBibleReading"/>
    </ComboBox.MaxWidth>
</ComboBox>
```

All good. This issue is that, when the song titles are displayed on the combo, I want to prefix the song titles with a 3 digit number. Eg:

> ```
> 001 - Song 1
> 002 - Song 2
> 003 - Song 3
> ```

Eventually, elsewhere in the application, I will want to use the combo box selected index to pull out the right song title (with no prefix) from the resources.

Is this possible?

Update:

If I create a XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <SongTitles>
    <SongTitle Number="1" Title = "Jehovah's Attributes"/>
  </SongTitles>
</Settings>
```

And add it as a resource to the WPF:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlData" Source="OCLM_Resources.xml" XPath="Settings/SongTitles" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then use:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboSongOpen"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData}, XPath=./SongTitle}" DisplayMemberPath="@Title">
    <ComboBox.MaxWidth>
        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" 
            ElementName="textWeeklyBibleReading"/>
    </ComboBox.MaxWidth>
</ComboBox>
```

That display the Title in the drop. But I can't quite get my head around using `ItemTemplate` and/or stiching to attributes (for formatting 0.000) together.

Comment: Are you really hard-coding the ComboBox entries or are they being inserted via `combobox.Items.Add` or a `DataSource`?

Comment: At the moment the big list of 154 titles is in the `app.xml` file as a resource. Eventually I need to support **localization**. I am not using the `Add` function call. I am using an `ItemSource` as per my question.

Comment: Can I suggest putting the song list into a file, and read that file when the application is being initialized, and then add them through `Items.Add`. This is a very simple solution to numbering/indexing your entries.

Comment: Will that also assist eventually with localization? If so, can I kindly ask that you provide an answer with your proposed methodology? I will upvote and accept.

Comment: Best bet is an item template. You'll need to add an index property to the items. Using the combobox selected index from elsewhere in the application is not a great idea. Just bind ComboBox.SelectedItem to an appropriately typed property in your viewmodel.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes I will be doing that (use typed property). Just not got that far yet.

Comment: In fact, "ComboBoxItemString" is a funny name for a class that's supposed to represent a song. Conceptually, the way to think about this in WPF is that you have a list of *song objects*. Write a class that represents a song, give it appropriate properties: Title, artist, year of release, etc. Display properties appropriately in the item template.

Comment: @EdPlunkett All I need is a song number and title. Nothing else.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Am I understanding you correctly that what you want is when the combobox's dropdown is not shown, you just the combobox to read "Song 1", but when the dropdown is visible, you want the drop down's list item to read "001 - Song 1", "002 - Song 2" etc?  Yea this is possible.

Comment: @user2880486 Not quite. I am hoping to have a single resource with the song titles. I think the datasource with attributes is way to go. It should just add the numeric prefix to all combo entries.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I just need clarification on the combobox.  Is what I described previously how you wanted the combobox to work?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can you please also show me your suggest of an ItemTemplate? I found this: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/

Comment: @AndrewTruckle You want the ItemTemplate/DataTemplate example in that article. I'm on my way out of town; if I have connectivity tonight I'll try to give you more specifics. You can search for examples here on SO, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple pure xaml solution.  You don't need to change anything else you have.

```
            //add this to your resource.  Obviously you should put this in code if you have lots of items
            <AlternationConverter x:Key="AlternateForegroundConverter">
                <s:Int16>1</s:Int16>
                <s:Int16>2</s:Int16>
                <s:Int16>3</s:Int16>
                <s:Int16>4</s:Int16>
                <s:Int16>5</s:Int16>
                //more if necessary
            </AlternationConverter>

        <ComboBox x:Name="comboSongOpen" ItemsSource="{StaticResource SongTitleString}" SelectedValuePath="ValueString" SelectedValue="{Binding SongTitle}" AlternationCount="99999" >
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:ComboBoxItemString">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, StringFormat='000 - ', Converter={StaticResource AlternateForegroundConverter}}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueString}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.MaxWidth>
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="textWeeklyBibleReading"/>
            </ComboBox.MaxWidth>
```

edit:  this namespace is needed

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Edit:  In response to updated question

Change the DataTemplate to (you won't need the AlternationConverter in this case).

```
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:ComboBoxItemString">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='000 - '}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueString}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

//add Number property to you class
public class ComboBoxItemString
{
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

//add the array
<x:Array x:Key="SongTitleString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 1" Number = "1" />
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 2" Number = "2" />
    <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 3" Number = "3" />
</x:Array>
```

There is a big HOWEVER.  You list is correct.  But if you select an item, the ComboBox will display "001 - Jehovah's Attributes" as well.  To get it to display "Jehovah's Attributes" only, you need to modify the control template.

Comment: Thanks. With my updated question which has the two attributes in the xml. Could we make use of that? I have 154 titles you see. So if we could combine with formatting the items in my xml. We are a winner. Doable?

Comment: Yes, but you sure you want to use the 2nd attribute?  The idea here is you don't have to manually set the Number at all.  What if you moved 100th song to first?  You would have to fix the 100 song numbers.

Comment: The ordering will not change. They represent the songs in a book. So it is fixed. I would prefer one set of data to manage. If possible please.

Comment: What's wrong with managing the data in the app.xaml as you originally had?  I don't see any scenario where you will end up managing more that one set of data.

Comment: If you think keeping it in xaml is better I can do that. When selected it should still say the number. After all the selected index is the song number. So I can get the theme again with a xpath lookup using index+1 as attribute.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think keeping it in app.config is best.  This means no external file to include.  You can change the songs w/o recompile.  You can localize easily too.  PS According to your current question, you don't need index at all.  We can return a ComboBoxItemString class object to SelectedItem of combobox.

Comment: Will look tomorrow. You say app.config. I was using app.xaml. I am not familiar with app.config. And how do we return the class object?

Comment: Goto project Settings, Select System.Collections.Specialized.StringColleciton as the type.  Enter a list of string as value.  This will create a section in app.config where its easy to change w/o needing recompile.   Usage example:  var songs = Properties.Settings.Default.songs;

Comment: I am able to modify the project as per your second idea in your answer. Please keep it there. But I am struggling to use the project Setting route. It sounds ideal but since it is a collection of strings the ItemTemplate needs to work differently. Can I kindly ask for a third part to your answer explaining how to use AppSettings property in ItemTemplate? Thanks. Sorry to be pain.

Comment: I do not recommend the setting with your new requirements.  It is much simpler to use app.xaml or XML now.

Answer (score 2):

As EdPlunkett suggested, refer the below sample using ItemTemplate of the ComboBox.

```
<Window x:Class="ChkList_Learning.Window2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChkList_Learning"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SongList}" x:Name="songsCombo">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text=" - "></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongName}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="ID"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding ElementName=songsCombo,Path=SelectedItem.Title}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Song Name"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Width="100"  Text="{Binding ElementName=songsCombo,Path=SelectedItem.SongName}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ChkList_Learning
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new SongViewModel();
        }
    }

    class SongViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Song> SongList { get; set; }

        public SongViewModel()
        {
            SongList = new ObservableCollection<Song>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Song song = new Song();
                song.Title = (i + 1).ToString();
                song.SongName = "Song Name" + (i + 1).ToString();
                song.AlbumName = "My Album";
                SongList.Add(song);
            }
        }
    }

    class Song
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string SongName { get; set; }

        public string AlbumName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look at this tomorrow. See if I can get that `SongList` populated from the XML file resource.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is more of a suggestion as per my comment on the OP:

If you offload the song list to a file, you can read the file in when the application is being initialized to create your song list. The actual structure of the file is up to you. CSV files are used typically, as that is a simple way of separating values (by comma), but you can use whatever delimiter you like.

In this case, given some of simple ways you can read files in C#, I may even suggest separating your song names by a new line. If you were to do this, to compile your song list would be as easy as:

```
string[] songList = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"songlist.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < songList.Length; i++) {
     string newItem = ((i+1).ToString()) + " " + songList[i];
     combo1.Items.Add(newItem);
}
```

OR

```
List<string> songs = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < songList.Length; i++) {
     songs.Add((i + 1).ToString() + " " + songList[i]);
}

combo1.ItemsSource = songs;
```

So in those examples the contents of the combobox will be

> 1 Song 1
>
> 2 Song 2

Edit: As per the last part of your post

> Eventually, elsewhere in the application, I will want to use the combo box selected index to pull out the right song title (with no prefix) from the resources.

In your example the format was `001 - Song 1`

If you want just the song title without the prefix, by `selectedIndex`, you have a few options.

1) You could have a 2nd list that you make when the application is initialized that simply does not contain the prefix. When you are compiling the lists, make a 2nd list, and add the song names without the prefix. You can then reference this list using the `selectedIndex` property of your `ComboBox`.

2) You can use the `selectedIndex` property and then use some variation of string manipulation to extract just the song name.

```
string[] selectedSong = combo1.Items[0].ToString().Split('-');
```

In this example, the song name without the prefix will be inside `selectedSong[1]`.

Comment: Thanks. I would want to use a XML file then which has the song titles and song numbers as attributes.. I was just hoping that, if the data was put into the other format, like XML with 2 attributes per item, that we could still do binding. I will look at what you wrote tomorroe. The otherthing is that the file needs to be in the resources because of localization.

Comment: Yes there are other methods of storing some list of items, that is mostly up to you. But if you do offload to some storage method instead of hard-coding, the method to put the items into the combobox will generally be something like this method.

Comment: This will also make the ComboBox.Text "1 Song 1", "2 Song 2" etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer as per the bottom portion of your OP

Comment: Splitting the strings is horrible and totally unnecessary. You put the index in with the ItemTemplate

Comment: @EdPlunkett as with most statements like this in programming, that is a complete red herring. Programmers (although they never think so) need to provide reasoning when they say "this is horrible", "that's awful", "never do that", otherwise, the statement is completely meaningless. Why is it horrible? Will it greatly degrade performance?

Answer (score 0):

just add a DisplayMemberPath with the prepend

```
<Application.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="SongTitleString" Type="local:ComboBoxItemString">
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 1" ValueStringLong = "# 1 Song 1"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 2" ValueStringLong = "# 2 Song 1"/>
        <local:ComboBoxItemString ValueString = "Song 3" ValueStringLong = "# 3 Song 1"/>
    </x:Array>
</Application.Resources>
```

DisplayMemberPath="ValueStringLong"